# Chain two css effect one after another with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I try to chain two css transition effect

Works well with animate :

```
$('.txt').css({'transition': 'transform .5s ease-in-out ', 
'transform': 'translate(30px, 30px)'}).delay(500)
.animate({fontSize:'2em'},0).delay(500)
.animate({height:100},0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vx2kpmo5/105/

What I actually want is not working properly, why ? :

```
$('.txt').css({'transition': 'transform .5s ease-in-out ', 
'transform': 'translate(30px, 30px)'}).delay(2000)
.css({'transition': 'transform 1.5s ease-in',
'transform': 'scale(1.1, 1.1)', 'transform-origin': 'top left'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vx2kpmo5/103/

Plus, how to tigger these animations for each .txt class one after another, not at the same as in the example above ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.delay()` only works with jQuery animations. Ditch it in your second example and add the [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) property instead.

```
$('.txt').css({
  'transition': 'transform .5s ease-in-out, font-size 1.5s ease-in 2s',
  'transform': 'translate(30px, 30px)',
  'font-size': '1.1rem',
  'transform-origin': 'center center, top left'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vy9vua9/

If you really need to use `transform` instead of `font-size` for the scaling effect, you'll need to rewrite things using [CSS keyframes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

Comment: Thanks ! That's a good solution, but if I use keyframes, it might work in my script ?
I need Jquery because this animation occurs when a specific button has been clicked.